# Kubernetes : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, gunicorn, locust

My Website is developed using Python Flask and deployed to Kubernetes and it is running with

```
gunicorn -k gevent --workers=8 --threads=5 apps.webapp:app
```

I am doing load test my project app with 100 users and Hatching rate 10 on locust, but everytime locust is throwing error after some requests with message

[image]:

I am struggling to find out the root cause of this issue. Is it Locust framework can't work on kubernetes website app? Please help to understand this issue.

Comment: Did you verify if your app is working and accessible via service ? f.e. from inside/outside the cluster.

Comment: yes its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extended ulimit to 3000, hence issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server seems to be resetting & closing the connection. This is most likely not related to locust itself (and would be a problem even with real users hitting your site)

Perhaps gunicorn can only handle 40 (8x5) simultaneous requests with those settings? What is your throughput?